# Find the maximum no of elements in Y given the following conditions?

Tags: number-theory

[image: Maximum no of elements]

**MyApproach**

Since X={9,15,21,27,33...375}

Then,Y={9,15,21,27..upto the middle of the set of elements X}.

So, X has 62 elements.

Therefore,Y must have 31 elements.

> Can Anyone guide me How to approach the problem?

Comment: Your approach looks fine to me. For each allowed $n$, we use one of $n$ or $384-n$. Small typo, it is $X$ that has $62$ elements.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ans is $31$  I checked it again.Thanku

Comment: It is easy to make an off by one error, but my count agrees with yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer of 31 is correct. $X=\{9+6n :0\leq n\leq 61\}$.Now $(9+6n_1)+(9+6n_2)=384\iff n_1+n_2=61.$ So for $0\leq n_1\leq 30$ at most one member of $\{9+6n_1,9+6(61-n_1)\}$ can belong to $Y$. So $Y$ has at most $31$ members.On the other hand if we do put one member of $\{9+6n_1,9+6(61-n_1)\}$ into $Y$ for each $n_1$ from $n_1=0$ up to $n_1=61$ then the condition on $Y$ is satisfied so $Y$ can indeed have $31$ members.